# How to make apps access my model without have to spread my model DLLS through them

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I have an architectural question. We have many applications in our company and we are planning to use ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework in our future projects. The next project that we need to implement is a central authorization/authentication system. There is no option to use an existing one for reasons that doesn't mater right now. This system probably will be structured as a service. What we don't know is: how the other applications will know about "the model" of this authorization/authentication system? I mean, how they will know user, roles, etc. classes? What is the best practice? One of our colleagues suggested to create the entity framework model (.edmx) in a class library. The problem is that in this case we should copy this dll for all projects that will access the authorization/authentication system. Is it a good solution? Does anybody has a better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to add to what DSO already said, the standard way to do this is through the "Add Sevice Reference" dialog box in Visual Studio.  It will query your web service, figure out the classes that are needed, and put them in a reference.cs file.  You can also use the svcutil.exe (or if you're using Silverlight, SLSvcUtil.exe) to do the same thing.  You have to regenerate the reference.cs file every time you change the interface of your web service, but that usually only takes a few seconds.

It's also possible to create a distinct set of Data Transfer Objects that can be shared back-and-forth between the various layers of your application, but unless you have very strong architectural requirements, I've found the auto-generated classes to work reasonably well.

See also this article here about the self-tracking entities available in EF 4.0, if that's an option for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335715.aspx.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement your service as a SOAP-based web service, which means your data model and methods will be exposed via SOAP and described using WSDL.  The web service can be consumed from any language, without requiring you to distribute any class libraries.

Many languages also have tools which auto-generate client side class wrappers based on WSDL description of your SOAP interface (e.g. wsdl.exe for .NET clients).